# How to pass dynamic value in request of API in Karate tool?

Tags: karate

```
Background:
* def TimeStamp = call read('classpath:Api/Mobile/Date.feature)
* def CurrentTime = TimeStamp.CurrentTimeStamp

Scenario: Client data is received
Given Url 'https://xxxxx/schd/migration'
And request {cn:1234,name:'Kiran',time:CurrentTime}
When method post
And print CurrentTime
Then print response


Date Feature File:

Background: Setup
* def pattern = 'MM/dd/yy hh.mm.ss'
* def getDate = 
   """
    function(){
      var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
      var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
      var date = new java.util.date();
      return sdf.format(date);
    }
 """
Scenario: Capture current date and time
 * string CurrentTimeStamp = getDate()
```

After running the feature file I am not seeing that tool is not replacing the parameter(time:CurrentTime) value in the request. But when i am printing the parameter value it is printing correctly

In line 6 ( in request) , i am trying to replace the value with dynamic value, but it is not reading

Comment: Tried ..but still it is not working.. Could you please write method..which would be helpful?